# What is the token for an original image URL?

Tags: 8, tokens, media

The is the token to get the url for a "large" image style:

```
[node:field_image:large:url]
```

What is the token that will give me the original file URL for the image?  That is, not an image style preset, but the original image.

I have tried the following:

```
[node:field_image]
[node:field_image:url]
[node:field_image:default:url]
[node:field_image:original:url]
[node:field_image:none:url]
```

None of these work.  I am trying to use the token in a field in the metatag config at admin/config/search/metatag/global.  The help text for the field assumes we want to use an image style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, this works for me:

```
[node:field_image:0:entity:url]
```